# How to create json file from mysql php query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to save the data retrieved from the database into a .json. This is what is just tried.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `positive`,`time` FROM sentiment WHERE acctid=1");


$response = array();
$posts = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 

$positive=$row['positive']; 

$time=$row['time']; 


$posts[] = array('positive'=> $positive, 'time'=> $time,);

} 

$response['posts'] = $posts;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```

I got the following errors:

```
Warning: fopen(results.json) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/getjson.php on line 29

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/getjson.php on line 30

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/getjson.php on line 31
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: do you have write permissions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test` isn't writable by Apache - change the permissions so it can write to it. In Windows Explorer, right click the `test` folder, and untick "Read Only".